# Javascript what is the best way to find a first item, that meet condition in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array of arrays looks like following,

```
const ar = [
   [2,6,7,9],
   [3,2,4,6],
   [7,8,9,10]
];
```

what will be a smart way to return the first item, that contains a number 3.
want to get an array `[3,2,4,6]`.
Thanks

Comment: Use `find()` to find the first item that matches a condition. Use `includes()` in the condition to test if the array contains `3`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am kind new to Javascripts, I have tried using for each, nest two for loops, all works. and I just want to know this there is another smart way to do that, I didn't know my question turned out to be against the rules

Comment: @YuJia I don't know if it was against the rules per se, but generallty the preferred method is describing what you want to accomplish clearly (you did this) and then showing what you have tried (didn't do this).  It is hidden in the term "smart" that you were looking for something that wasn't "brute force", and while some might interpret that signal not everybody will.  Next time think: "here is my brute force method" but I want something more a little more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
ar.find(innerAr -> innerAr.includes(3))
```

should work. I would encapsulate the solution along these lines:

```
 const findInnerArrayWith = val => arr => 
        arr.find(innerAr -> innerAr.includes(val))
```

in use this would be:

```
 const findInnerArrayWith3 = findInnerArrayWith(3)
 const inner = findInnerArrayWith(ar)
```

or if you want to run multiple queries against the array (holding the array constant and varying the object to find) I might flip the parameters

```
 const findIn = arr => val => 
        arr.find(innerAr -> innerAr.includes(val))

 const findInAr = findIn(ar)
 const inner = findInAr(3)
```

maybe thats a bit beyond the scope of the question - but the order of the parameters opens up some interesting approaches to structuring your code.

*references*

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how you can do it with array [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Simply put, array.find looks for the first element matches an condition. And the condition is where the array.indexOf comes in to check the membership of target in an array.

```
const ar = [
   [2,6,7,9],
   [3,2,4,6],
   [7,8,9,10]
];
const target = 3; // the target number you are looking

let result = ar.find( a => a.indexOf(3) !== -1);
```